# Monitor folder for new file using #!bin/sh shell script, if there is, trigger another shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I need a script that monitors a shared folder i created between ubuntu and windows. The script will trigger another script upon detection of new .exe files in the shared folder on ubuntu.

If anyone have ideas for a shell script like this, do share it with me here, i need it urgently, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I love the idea with `dnotify` but also want to suggest a quick-and-dirty solution:

```
while true
do 
  ls /dir/*.exe > current-list
  if diff current-list old-list
  then
    # do something with new files
    diff current-list old-list | grep '^<' | while read x file 
    do
       # make an operation with new file $file
    done && mv current-list old-list
  fi
  sleep 1
done
```

I want to note that that just a "proof-of-concept", you need to tune the script a little bit (file names, directories, error handling and so on).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at **dnotify** ( http://linux.die.net/man/1/dnotify )

Comment: I tried using dnotify in a while loop, however, it executes the samplescript immediately even when there is no file created in the directory, and despite using while loop the dnotify command doesn't executes the sameplescript again even after i created files in the directory.